# Cursor disappears temporarily after opening the Assembly Language Editor in DOSBox

Tags: x86-16, dosbox

I recently installed DOSBox (version 0.74-3) and attempted to write x86 assembly code within it. However, upon opening the editor using the edit command, I encountered an issue where the cursor disappears temporarily. It's quite inconvenient, and I'm facing the same problem on both Linux Ubuntu and Windows 10. How can I resolve this?

"I've tried a few things to resolve this issue. First, I attempted to change the display settings within DOSBox, thinking that it might be related to the cursor visibility. However, this did not have any effect on the disappearing cursor problem. I also checked the DOSBox documentation and online forums for similar issues, but I couldn't find a specific solution.

Comment: The text cursor in freshly opened EDIT.COM is not visible, you should create a file first (with **File/N**ew with default name *Untitled*).  However, there are much better editors than EDIT.COM.

Comment: I pulled up DOSBOX and happened to run EDIT.COM from DOS6.22 and sure enough I observed the cursor intermittently disappearing BUT the menu becomes activated as if the ALT key was pressed (when it wasn't) so the cursor disappeared because it was navigating the menu until I hit ESCape to close the menu and continue editing. Is this by chance what you are seeing?

Comment: I found in my case that the problem was resolved by adding `usescancodes=false` in the `[sdl]` of the DosBox CONF file in my `~/.dosbox` directory. I found this solution in this old Ubuntu bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dosbox/+bug/283273

Comment: If you set up DOSBox so it can see files on the host system, you should be able to use your normal editor on your asm source, and only use DOSBox for running it and a debugger.  (You can assemble+link either inside or outside DOSBox, depending on what toolchain you want to use.  NASM works well to produce a flat `.com` binary)